# Login into phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using XAMPP in Windows 8. How can I Login into phpMyAdmin ??  I tried a lot but failed to login.

[image]

Comment: You have to configure the connection to the mysql server you use first. That configuration is done in a configuration file. Take a look at the documentation phpmyadmin provides. That will answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your phpmyadmin credentials by defaut try this though, it may work 
`Try username = root and password is blank.`
 You can also add to your /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file this line: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

On windows you will find this file under your phpmyadmin installation. (I left it that way fro the next curious linux user)

Answer (score 1):

You have set up a ["control user"](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/qa_4_4/config.html#cfg_Servers_controluser) for phpMyAdmin. But this account does not exist in the MySQL user credentials. So either you disable the control user in the phpMyAdmin configuration file, or you set up the user account in MySQL and make sure the credentials match in your phpMyAdmin configuration.

The control user is required for [phpMyAdmin's configuration storage](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/qa_4_4/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage). phpMyAdmin works without as well, but is less comfortable.